# My CTR increased from 2% to 4,39%, is it normal?

Tags: admob

I usually see my CTR constant to value `2,..%` after it increased to `4.39%"`, is it normal? And what is the normal value? If it isn't a normal value, what do I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that 5+% CTR may be a ban reason. There are no automatic ban however, moderator will check your app before banning you. If you are not violating their policies (not placed banner near buttons or above clickable content) - all is right. Normal CTR is around 2% (as I read from different forums, again).

However if your CTR is jumping so high, you might have a little number of users and small revenue (like 10-30 cents per day). I believe moderator is not checking such apps. However when you reach 50$, I belive he will come and check your app before allow you to get your money.

The legal way to reduce CTR is to set refresh rate to 30 seconds. That will have some effect. Other ways (like hiding banner or frequently refreshing) are bad and may become a ban reason.
But It only my assumes all above. If anyone can explain better, please do so. I am also interested in this question!